# What is the best way of making an MP4 from an image sequence (PNG)

Tags: export

I have rendered 80 individual frames from blender in 1080p. what is the best method for creating a high-quality MP4 file with disregard to size limitations for maximum quality. I read that blender re-encodes files which apparently is bad, so is there an alternate program that I must use and what are the optimal settings. Even if I should just use blender, what are the optimal settings as the default settings created a blurry pixelated MP4 from my high quality pngs.

Apologies if this has already been answered somewhere else

Thank you in advance for any support you can provide

Comment: Please add reference images/screenshots to help answering your question.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the given answer is not specific enough for you. If you want an MP4 with best quality I would suggest (since you don't care about file size) to choose the following settings:

1. *File Format:* FFmpeg video
2. *Container:* MPEG-4
3. *Video Codec:* H.264
4. *Output Quality*: Perceptually lossless (with 'Lossless' I once had playback issues, might be because MP4 cannot be completely lossless, I'm satisfied with using 'High quality')
5. *Encoding Speed:* Slowest (should give best quality, but I see no advantage over 'Good')

Normally this should produce quite good results, although MP4 is not a lossless format it usually provides high quality along with a good compression i.e. small filesize.

Comment: Thank you for the comment Gordon, but I have tried every combination of high bitrates and samples and codecs, the render will not be high resolution. If you check my profile and my post recent post I have a visual example. The rendered video even in avi raw is desaturated and grainy.

Comment: Just a stupid question: are your PNG files 8-bit or 16-bit?

Comment: Im new to this there are no stupid questions, but im not sure. When i import the png into photoshop it says RGB/8 at the top which the internet says means its 32 bit.

Comment: No, if it says RGB/8 at the top then it's exactly what it says, 8 which means 8-bit. I was just wondering because PNGs can be 8-bit or 16-bit, but MP4s only 8-bit. So if your PNGs would have a higher bit depth this might have been a reason. Another possibility could be the player's capability of showing color grades etc. but then no setting will help you, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

The generated video from blender video sequencer should not have a lower quality at all. Double check your render settings for lowered resolution or bitrate, or possibly a poor encoding format. H264 is a good video codec for the MP4 container.

Comment: No matter what settings I put it renders a lower resolution video. The individual frames are all 4k, so its not the models. Even exporting in avi raw produces a slightly grainy video. I also noticed compared to the stills the avi raw has less colour.

Comment: You are using the blender video sequencer, right?